# Batch download of URLs with unknown timestamp

Tags: batch, download

There are a list of pictures with URLs of the format

```
https://www.eol.ucar.edu/rsf/image_archive/timrex/spol/080616/SPOL_20080616{HHMMSS}_1.1_SUR_4pan.png
```

That I would like to download.

For example:
https://www.eol.ucar.edu/rsf/image_archive/timrex/spol/080616/SPOL_20080616000051_1.1_SUR_4pan.png

The timestamps range from 00:00:00 to 23:00:00, and are not spaced regularly. I do not know how many images in total there are.

How can I download all of the files under that url format? I have a windows and linux machine.

Comment: There are 82,800 possible permutations here. However, when one that doesn't exist is attempted to be reached, is a HTTP status 404 returned?

Comment: Yes, a 404 is returned. My current solution is to just loop a wget through all possible permutations...but I'm wondering of there is a faster way

Comment: [PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest) iterating is another way. Not sure that  you'll not have to try every possible second on the timestamps though without trying all possible URLs. Like Michael Jackson said, **"Just Iterate It!!"**